# Finding the area of a triangle in a circle from a point.

Tags: coordinate-systems

> $P$ is variable point. Tangents are drawn to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ from $P$ to touch it at $ Q$ and $R$. The parallelogram $PQSR$ is completed. If $P $ is $(6,8) $, then find the area of $QSR$.

I have been trying to solve this question since a long time but I'm unable to do so. I tried to find the coordinates of intersection of the tangents but the calculation was a mess.  I also tried to use the fact that $PQOR$ is a cyclic quadrilateral but it did not prove to be helpful. I have run out of ideas. Would someone please help me to solve this question in an elegant and simple manner?

Comment: Where can i find an image of this problem?

Comment: Does the line "$L = 0$" mean $\{(x,0)\}$  i.e. the points satisfying $y =0$?

Comment: What is the line L exactly? You haven't typed the formula correctly.

Comment: @fleeblood No, is just an equation of a line.

Comment: What does $L =0$ mean then?  What line *is* this?

Comment: Usually an equation of a line needs to relate the variables $x$ and $y$ together.  Most commonly as $y = mx + b$ but often as $ax + by = c$.  If the line is horizontal then $y$ is always a constant and we write $y=c$ (and $x$ will be any value).  And if the line is vertical $x$ is always a constant so we write $x =k$.  But writing "$L=0$" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There is no need of $L =0$. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from $P$ to the origin is $\sqrt{6^2+8^2} = 10$, so it is equivalent to let the point $P$ at (0,10) due to rotation invariance around the origin and the computation gets a lot easier due to symmetry.

Let $2\theta = \angle QPR$. Then, you have

$$\sin\theta = \frac{2}{10}=  \frac{1}{5}$$

Since $\angle RQO = \theta$ due to similar triangles, then the area QSR is

$$ (10-2\sin\theta)\cdot2\cos\theta$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: It's not true that $|\angle RQS|= \theta$. You have $|\angle RQO|=\theta$, but $O \neq S$. $O= (0,0)$ is the center of the circle, but $S$ is a point that completes the paralellogram $PQSR$.  Correctly you have $\triangle QSR \equiv \triangle QPR$.

Comment: you're right. will correct

Answer (score 1):

Since $PQSR$ is a paralleogram, then area of $\triangle QSR$ is the same as the area of $\triangle QPR$.

Since $PQ$ and $PR$ are fragments of lines tanget to the circle, it means that traingles $PQ \perp QO$ and $PR \perp RO$. It also means that $QR \perp PO$.

Let $K$ be the intersection point of lines $PO$ and $RQ$. We have $$ {\rm Area}(\triangle PQR) = 2 \cdot {\rm Area}(\triangle PQK)$$ Then triangles $PKQ$ and $PQO$ are similar right triangles, with the scale of similiarity being $$ \lambda = {{|PQ|}\over{|PO|}}$$ 
That means that $$ {\rm Area}(\triangle PQK) = \lambda^2 \cdot {\rm Area}(\triangle PQO) = \frac{|PQ|^2}{|PO|^2} \cdot \frac12 |PQ| |QO| = \frac{|PQ|^3|QO|}{2|PO|^2}$$
$$ {\rm Area}(\triangle PQR) = \frac{|PQ|^3|QO|}{|PO|^2}$$
We have  $|PO| = \sqrt{6^2+8^2} = 10$, $|QO|=2$ (the radius of the circle), and from the Pythagoras' theorem, $|PQ|=\sqrt{10^2-2^2}=4\sqrt{6}$. That means that $$ {\rm Area}(\triangle PQR) = \frac{(4\sqrt{6})^3\cdot 2}{10^2} = \frac{192\sqrt{6}}{25}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q = (x_0, y_0)$ And let $R=(x_1, y_1)$.

So $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 4$.  The line from the origin of the circle $O$ to $Q$ is $\frac {y_0}{x_0}$.  So the slope of the tangent line is $-\frac {x_0}{y_0}$.

$P =(6,8)$ is on this line so $y_0 - 8 = -(x_0 -6)\frac {x_0}{y_0}$

Or $y_0^2 - 8y_0 = -x_0^2 + 6x_0$

Or $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 6x_0 + 8y_0$

Or $4 = 6x_0 + 8y_0$

Or $y_0 = -\frac 34 x_0+\frac 12$.

But we know $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 4$ so $x_0^2 + (-\frac 34 x_0+\frac 12)^2 = 4$.

Some thing can be done for $x_1, y_1$

We will have $y_1 =-\frac 34 x_1 + \frac 12$ and $x_1^2 + (-\frac 34 x_1+\frac 12)^2 = 4$.

So...

Solve the equation $x^2 + (-\frac 34x + \frac 12)^2 = 4$.

You will get two answers.  One will be $x_0$ and the other will by $x_1$.  Plug them into the equations $y_i = -\frac 34 x_i+\frac 12$ to find $y_0$ and $y_1$.

Those we know the coordinates of $P,Q, R$.  $S$ can be found by completing the parallelogram but may not be needed.

Can you finish?